# Sort negative dimension values in Qliksense?

Tags: qliksense

I have a bar chart in Qlik sense. X- axis dimension looks like -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5 but I am not able to sort the x-axis.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this sorting issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your chart is sorted by your measure on the Y axis rather than the dimension on the X axis. You should just be able to go to the chart properties and change the sort order to sort by your dimension on the X axis.

However if the numbers are stored as text you may first need to convert them as Qlik Sense may not recognise the correct sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You can selection the dimension as numeric and apply sorting on it